# What should last task in a chain return - c++ rest sdk?

Tags: c++, rest, casablanca

In the following code, why is variable `t` assigned a correct task when neither of lambdas in the chain return such a type? The lambdas return `task<http_response>`, `task<json::value>` and none.

The code works when the last lambda returns task and when it returns nothing.

Any pointers to online docs that shed some light on it will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
pplx::task<void> t = client.request(methods::GET, L"/api/dummy")
.then([](http_response response)
{
    if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        response.content_ready().wait();
        return response.extract_json(); // return task<json::value>
    }
})

.then([](json::value value)
{
    if (value.has_field(L"id"))
    {
        int id = value.at(L"id").as_integer();
    }

    // t.wait() below works regardless if this  
    // line is commented out or not.
    //return pplx::task<void>({});
});

try
{
    t.wait();
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    [...]
}
```

Comment: well what is that `[...]`? it is the key of understanding what is hapenning here

Comment: [...] represents a code that mainly does extraction of data from json - definitely no task of any kind created/returned there.  I updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`then` always returns some kind of task, take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj987787.aspx). if the callback supplied to `then` does not return anything `then` will just return `task<void>`.
in a nut shell, `then` will return a task that correspond to the return type of the callable supplied to `then`

```
task<T> t1 = t0.then([]{ return T(); });
task<void> t2 = t3.then([]{ /*return nothing*/ });
```

let's break this to parts:

```
task<http_response> t0 = client.request(methods::GET, L"/api/dummy");
task<json::value value> t1 = t0.then(/*return json from response*/);
task<void> t = t1.then(/*extract "id", returns nothing*/);
t.wait();
```

now, take a look on what happens when you use `co_await`:

```
 auto response = co_await client.request(methods::GET, L"/api/dummy");
  if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        response.content_ready().wait();
        auto value = co_await response.extract_json();
        if (value.has_field(L"id"))
        {
           int id = value.at(L"id").as_integer();
        }
    }
```

isn't it neat? the entire continuation chaining just collapsed to synchronous code, but the code is still asynchronous behind the scenes!

Comment: Got it! I missed "The result type of the returned task is determined by what _Func returns" in the docs.  Thanks.